# Amenability; topology on power sets

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-groups, amenability

I am currently reading the proof of Proposition 2.2. (a direct limit of discrete amenable groups is amenable) in http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/kar/amenable.pdf .
The proof uses the Tychonoff theorem for $[0,1]^{P(G)}$, where $G$ is a discrete group. What is the topology used there on the power set $P(G)$?

Comment: My first guess is the *discrete topology*, or, so to say, *doesn't use topology* at all: $[0,1]^{P(G)}$ might be seen as the product $\prod_{A\in P(G)}[0,1]$.

Comment: @Berci thanks! I somehow tend to think this as well, but I wanted to hear opinions of other people. In the end it doesnt matter what topology we use, as long as the sets there are closed, isn't it?

Comment: Well, Tychonoff is about *product* spaces. Also, $G$ is discrete. What topology would we put on $P(G)$ and then what to do about it?

Comment: @Berci yeah good point, of course I know what Tychonoff says, but I now see that this is the only topology to make sense

Answer (score 1):

No topology on $\mathcal{P}(G)$ is being used here.  Tychonoff's theorem is applied to the product topology on the product $[0,1]^{\mathcal{P}(G)}$ of copies of $[0,1]$ indexed by the set $\mathcal{P}(G)$.  The topology on a product space is defined only in terms of products on the factors, not a topology on the index set.